# Test for difference between groups: percentage variable

Tags: anova, t-test, multiple-comparisons, proportion, percentage

I have 1249 census tracts in Colorado. I've grouped them into three groups, based on whether or not they are in "hot spots, "cold spots", or "neither" for their smoking prevalence (%). I'm trying to see if the proportion of adults living in poverty are statistically different among these groups. For each of the 1249 tracts I have an observation value expressed as the % of people in poverty.

Can I do an ANOVA/t-test on this? It's bounded data between 0-100. I thought I need to do Chi-Square instead since it's proportion data. The data are not normally distributed:

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do I impute from neighther ? It is not zero . Neither hot nor cold '-- average ? Chi-square test is not suitable given your objective.